# List with multiple data type

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, soap, soa

| date of delivery | compagny name | quantity |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 11-15-2019 | moon | 450 |
| 01-01-2010 | sun | 10 |

I want to create a list for the above table but my code doesn't seem to work. The `<deliv>` is highlited red and I get the error message cs0246:

```
listdelivery = new List<deliv>();
listdelivery.Add(new deliv() { datedeliv = "11 - 15 - 2019", Compagny = "Moon", quantity = "450" });
listdelivery.Add(new deliv() { datedeliv = "01 - 01 - 2010", Compagny = "Sun", quantity = "10" });
```

I'm trying to use the list to search for deliveries using the date as an input, I clearly did something wrong but I cant seem to find it and I do not know what to look for on the internet.

Comment: `datedeliv = 11 - 15 - 2019` is wrong. it should be `datedeliv = "11-15-2019"`.  What you did is using math. The number 11 minus 15 minus 2019.

Comment: welcome to stackoverflow. can you please be more specific than"doesn't seem to work"? what is happening that shouldn't? do you get any error messages? also: did you know that `11 - 15 - 2019` is not a date, but a mathematical expression evaluating to `-2023`? i recommend [taking the tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour), as well as reading [how to ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [what's on topic](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic).

Comment: If datedeliv is a Datetime object then even `"11-15-2019"` wont work. You would need to convert the string to Datetime.

Comment: the problem is that <deliv> doesnt seem to be recognised and its highlited red

Comment: Show the code for the deliv class. If you haven't defined deliv class, define it and give properties datedeliv, Compagny, quantity etc

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am guessing you need to create your `deliv` type as some kind of DTO with date, name and quantity fields. And also, as suggested earlier, if you want proper search by date, then Date field of your deliv type should be DateTime

Comment: thank you , i realised that i needed to define deliv as a class